# Role based login in JSP with Struts

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts2, mysql-workbench

I always get an error if I login with a user roled as ADMIN and if the user logging in is not in the database. The only time it works is when the user is in the database with a role USER.

Here are my codes:

Login.jsp

This page is where the user will login bot ADMIN and USER.

```
<st:form action="mylogin" cssClass="form">
<st:textfield input="Email" placeholder="Email" name="uemail" cssClass="form__input" ></st:textfield>
<st:textfield input="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="upass" cssClass="form__input" ></st:textfield>
<st:submit  cssClass="btn" value="Login"></st:submit>
</st:form>
```

struts.xml

This is where the login page will be redirected and will be passed to the LoginAction.

```
<action name="mylogin" class="com.lithan.mp3.action.LoginAction">
            <result name="SUCCESS">/admins.jsp</result>
            <result name="INPUT">/logins.jsp</result>
            <result name="ERROR">/logine.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

LoginAction

This action will check the role of the user and also if the information is in the database.

```
public class LoginAction{  
    private String uemail,upass; 

    public String execute() throws Exception{
        String flag=null;
        Admin impl=new Admin();
        MyLogin my=impl.loginDetail(uemail, upass);
        boolean data=my.isFlag();
        if(data) {
            if(my.getUrole().equals("ADMIN")) {
                return "SUCCESS";
            }else {
                return "INPUT";
            }
            
        }else {
            flag= "ERROR";
        }
        return flag;
    }
//getter setters
}
```

MyLogin.java

The getter and setter of the informations fetch in the database.

```
public class MyLogin {
    String uemail,upass,urole;
    boolean flag;
    
    public MyLogin() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    
    public MyLogin(String uemail, String upass, String urole, boolean flag) {
        super();
        this.uemail = uemail;
        this.upass = upass;
        this.urole = urole;
        this.flag = flag;
    }
//getter and setters
}
```

dao.Admin.java

The connection of database and website.

```
// method for fetch saved user data
        public ResultSet report() throws SQLException, Exception {
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                String sql = "SELECT UNAME,UEMAIL,UDEP,UPASS,UROLE FROM USER";
                PreparedStatement ps = getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
                return rs;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (getConnection() != null) {
                    getConnection().close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the problem? Add user to the database with the role ADMIN.

Comment: My admin works now but when I give data thats not in database it doesnt go to my error page but gives me HTTP Statys 500

Comment: First, you didn't say it in the question. Second, It is because the exception is occured in your code and it's not handled. If you entered data that is not in the database then check what is returned by the DAO method. If it returns `null` then in your code `NullPointerException` is thrown and it should be handled.

Comment: Can you show me how to revise the could and handle it? Because my teacher said "Your mapping is not correct" and just seen all of my messages. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, your mapping is not correct. Check the server log and post a sacktrace of error.